# Will CA's revoke a certificate to phishing websites

Tags: certificates, web-browser

Usually, websites will say "don't sign in unless you see the secure icon". If the user hasn't noticed that the URL is wrong (or is misleading like [this](https://www.wordfence.com/blog/2017/04/chrome-firefox-unicode-phishing/) recent security firm has discovered), and purely trusts that icon, they may fall victim to a phishing attack. In this case, would a CA revoke the phishing site's certificate, or am I missing the point of revocation? Also, if CAs do revoke certificates for phishing sites, are there any well known examples?

Comment: See also [Who is responsible for revoking a certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127988/who-is-responsible-for-revoking-a-certificate)

Comment: See also [The CA's Role in Fighting Phishing and Malware](https://letsencrypt.org/2015/10/29/phishing-and-malware.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this differs for each CA. According to a Technical Support Specialist at [GlobalSign](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/10/13/globalsigned_off/):

> GlobalSign does not revoke certificate without the permission of the owner. [...] For phishing sites, our vetting team will perform security checks on the domain prior to issuance.

On the other hand, [DigiCert](https://www.digicert.com/certificate-revocation.htm) has some other rules:

> DigiCert revokes certificates for the reasons stated in the DigiCert CPS, including the following:
>
> - [...]
> - DigiCert obtains evidence that the certificate was misused;
> - DigiCert is made aware that a subscriber has violated one or more of its material obligations under its agreement with DigiCert;
> - A third party provides information that leads the DigiCert to believe that the code signing certificate is compromised or is being used for suspect code;

Furthermore, a certificate is meant to indicate that you are really connected to the right site. It does not give a judgement about the content or quality of the site. A certificate for fake-paypal.com is valid and correct if you are really connected to fake-paypal.com, even if that site impersonates the real PayPal.

Edit: DigiCert revokes certificates that have been "misused", but what this exactly means is open for interpretation. I think using a certificate for a man-in-the-middle attack is definitely misuse, but I am not sure about using it on a phishing site.

Comment: Which of the points do you feel would be relevant for DigiCert to revoke a certificate for a phishing site? For example, does the DigiCert agreement include terms like "you agree not to make a site that appears overly similar to some other site", and who is the arbitrer of that?

Comment: I actually don't think DigiCert generally revokes phishing site certificates. But they could, because "misuse" could mean a lot of things.